# How can I specify dependencies on operating system in Python Poetry?

Tags: python, operating-system, dependencies, markers, python-poetry

If I want to develop a Python package which works only in Linux and macOS. How do I specify this restriction in Python Poetry?

Comment: Could you share your `pyproject.toml` file?

Comment: Sure! https://gitlab.com/JoD/exact/-/blob/master/python/pyproject.toml

Answer (score 10):

[Trove classifiers](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#classifiers) in the `pyproject.toml` file can be used to specify which operating systems are supported. For Linux and MacOS this would be:

```
[tool.poetry]
classifiers = [
    "Operating System :: MacOS",
    "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux"
]
```

This will however not prevent poetry from attempting to install the package on other platforms when the `poetry install` command is used. Support for platform-specific wheel tags has been suggested in [GitHub issue #2051](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2051), which is on the [to do list for poetry's 1.2 release](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/projects/6#card-63739470) at the time of writing.

To specify which platforms to install the package on as a dependency of another poetry project, [environment markers](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers) can be used:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
yourpackage = {version = "*", markers = "sys_platform == 'linux' or sys_platform == 'darwin'"}
```

Poetry will then ignore `yourpackage` when `poetry install` is used on other platforms, but not give any errors. If it is a hard dependency, it would therefore be better to indicate elsewhere which platforms are supported.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers), they mention environment markers are supported, you could use the `sys_platform` marker.

Comment: Interesting, I missed that. So now I've added two lines to the `pyproject.toml` file of the package:
```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
sys_platform = "linux"
platform_machine = "x86_64"
```
and ran `poetry build`. However, the resulting wheel name still is `package-version-py3-none-any.whl` instead of the expected `package-version-py3-linux-x86_64.whl`. 

I'm not quite getting the hang of it yet...

Comment: I do not know if this would work but try this,
`[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = {version="^3.7", markers="sys_platform=='linux'"}`

Comment: Hmm, yeah, using `[tool.poetry.dependencies] cppyy = {version="^2.1.0", markers="sys_platform=='linux'"}` compiles, but does not change the `none-any.whl`. I also have the feeling this changes the platform constraints of the dependency of the package, rather than the platform constraints of the package itself.